# replace string on condition - php

Tags: php, conditional-statements, str-replace

i am facing an issue here , trying to replace string with another under a condition.
check the example :

```
$data = '
tony is playing with toys.
tony is playing with "those toys that are not his" ';
```

so i want to replace **toys** with **cards** . but only which is NOT in ques (**"**).

i know how to replace all words that are **toys**  .

```
$data = str_replace("toys", "cards",$data);
```

but i don't know how to add a condition which specifies to replace only the one's which are not in the (**"**).

can anyone help please ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's one simple way to do it.  Split/explode your string using quotation marks.  The first (`0`-index) element and each even-numbered index in the resulting array is unquoted text; the odd numbers are inside quotes.  Example:

```
Test "testing 123" Test etc.
^0    ^1          ^2
```

Then, just replace the magic words (toys) with the replacement (cards) in only the even-numbered array elements.

Sample code:

```
function replace_not_quoted($needle, $replace, $haystack) {
    $arydata = explode('"', $haystack);

    $count = count($arydata);
    for($s = 0; $s < $count; $s+=2) {
        $arydata[$s] = preg_replace('~'.preg_quote($needle, '~').'~', $replace, $arydata[$s]);
    }
    return implode($arydata, '"');
}

$data = 'tony is playing with toys.
tony is playing with toys... "those toys that are not his" but they are "nice toys," those toys';

echo replace_not_quoted('toys', 'cards', $data);
```

So, here, the sample data is:

```
tony is playing with toys.
tony is playing with toys... "those toys that are not his" but they are "nice toys," those toys
```

The algorithm works as expected and produces:

```
tony is playing with cards.
tony is playing with cards... "those toys that are not his" but they are "nice toys," those cards
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to parse the string to identify the regions that are not within quotes. You can do this with a state-machine or regular-expression that supports counting.

Here's a pseudocode example:

```
typedef Pair<int,int> Region;
List<Region> regions;

bool inQuotes = false;
int start = 0;
for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
    char c = str[i];
    if( !inQuotes && c == '"' ) {
        start = i;
        inQuotes = true;
    } else if( inQuotes && c == '"' ) {
        regions.add( new Region( start, i ) );
        inQuotes = false;
    }

}
```

Then split the string up according to `regions`, each alternate region will be in quotes.

Challenge for the reader: get it so it handles escaped quotes :)

Comment: do you have php example ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex and use a negative lookaround to find the line without the quotes then do a string replace on that.

```
^((?!\"(.+)?toys(.+)?\").)*
```

e.g.

```
preg_match('/^((?!\"(.+)?toys(.+)?\").)*/', $data, $matches);
$line_to_replace = $matches[0];
$string_with_cards = str_replace("toys", "cards", $line_to_replace);
```

OR if there are multiple matches you might want to iterate over the array.

http://rubular.com/r/t7epW0Tbqi

Comment: thanx @Oliver , i tried to run your example to understand it but it didn't work with me , can you please clarify more or another example with result ?

Comment: @Hussein the example was psudeo code, I haven't played with PHP for a while but the logic is still valid. Did you check the rubular link I gave you as that gives you visual feedback?

Comment: yes i did , but i couldnt find make it work in php .. it doesnt give the same result.